# How to reset to original state after calling spriteBatch.setTransformMatrix(Matrix4 matrix4)?

Tags: libgdx

I want to rotate my drawing, but after that I don't know how to reset to the original no-rotation state.

```
spriteBatch.begin();
spriteBatch.setTransformMatrix(matrix4);
//draw something here
spriteBatch.end();
```

I have tried `spriteBatch.getTransformMatrix().idt()` but it does not work

Comment: What exactly do you want to rotate? Probably you should not manipulate this matrix directly, but by using a camera for example. Furthermore if you just want to rotate a single image, you'd supply a rotation value to the drawing methods instead of rotating the whole batch via the transform matrix.

Comment: I have a camera, it maps to my whole screen. But I just want to rotate a single image. That is the method `bitmapFont.draw(...)` I don't find any rotation. parameter that I can pass to this method. So I must rotate the whole batch and then rotate it back. Is that right?

Comment: That might work, use the camera to rotate it, and then use the camera to rotate it back. In between do spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined) and don't alter the transform matrix at all.